# Extract all status codes from a JSON response using a regex

Tags: java, regex, elasticsearch

I would like to extract all the status codes from a JSON response ([Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html) response to a [bulk request](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)) so that I can count how many documents have been created and how many errored.

Which regex should I use in the following code?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
 import java.util.regex.Pattern;    
 ...

 List<String> allCodes = new ArrayList<String>();
 Matcher m = Pattern.compile("regex").matcher(jsonResponseString);
 while (m.find()) {
   allCodes.add(m.group());
 }
```

Example of JSON response:

```
{
  "took": 9,
  "errors": false,
  "items": [
    {
      "index": {
        "_index": "movies",
        "_type": "drama",
        "_id": "123",
        "_version": 68,
        "result": "updated",
        "_shards": {
          "total": 2,
          "successful": 1,
          "failed": 0
        },
        "created": false,
        "status": 200
      }
    },
    {
      "index": {
        "_index": "movies",
        "_type": "drama",
        "_id": "456",
        "_version": 1,
        "result": "created",
        "_shards": {
          "total": 2,
          "successful": 1,
          "failed": 0
        },
        "created": true,
        "status": 201
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you don't use jackson to create java objects and then read the status ?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that those objects won't change in future versions of elastic? And we're talking about thousand of objects, I'm concerned about performances. Thanks

Comment: Don't try to parse json by yourself. There have been libraries developed to handle json etc. On your Elasticsearch topic I found a tutorial/example which may help you: http://bytefish.de/blog/elasticsearch_java/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 List<String> allCodes = new ArrayList<String>();

 Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"status\": (\\d.*)").matcher(YOUR_TEXT);

while (m.find()) {
        allCodes.add(m.group(1));
    }

    System.out.println(allCodes);
```

But i would create a Pojo with just the information you want:

e.g

```
public class Response {

    int took;
    List<Item> itemList;

        class Item{
            int status;
        }
}
```

and then use jackson to convert.

By the way there is a java api for elasticsearch: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html so you don't need to handle parsing etc.

Answer (score 1):

If status is just a numbers, you can use something like this `\"status\":\s+(\d+)`. Also if you will use `group()` you will get all matched sequences: `"status": 200, "status": 201`

```
    List<String> allCodes = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"status\":\\s+(\\d+)").matcher(jsonResponseString);
    while (m.find()) {
        allCodes.add(m.group(1));
    }
    System.out.println(allCodes);
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment, you shouldn't use a regex. If you think parsing the full JSON graph is too memory-consuming and don't want to use a Elastic search Java client, you may want to consider:

https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath

Lightweight library which is simmilar to XPath for XML, but for JSON. It doesn't parse the full model into memory but streams it and only extracts the matching elements, based on the path you supply. In this case this path would be something like:

```
 $.items[?(@status = 200)]
```

I think you can even have the expression immediatly return the count you're looking for by using `.length()`, without the need to count the matching elements manually...